# Should initial Git commit contain auto generated files?

Tags: git, versioning

So far I was developing without versioning software and my application contains many files (functionality, configuration files and auto-generated files). Now another two people will be working on this project so I want to use Git for our cooperation.

I'm new to Git. I just set up Git repository on my server. I want to develop on my notebook and then commit changes to the server. Now I'm not sure about how the first commit should look.

Should I include all the files (auto-generated files, config files and functionality files) into first commit, so my colleagues could easily checkout and get full project data to their localhosts or should I commit only functionality files (exclude pictures, auto-generated files, configuration files, etc.) ?

If I commit everything, they can checkout and then ingnore config files (because they have to edit them to fit their localhost environment) and auto-generated files from future commits.

What is the best practise for this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best practice would be to create a .gitignore file ignoring backups, compiled files, host dependent files, ide dependent files and stuff you don't want in the global repository because they don't make sense there. Only the stuff necessary to compile and run the project should be in your repository (and perhaps some project management stuff like gloabal todo lists, instructions, readme etc.).

Global, stable config file (like makefiles, maven pom and such) of course should be included since they are needed to build the project.

Make your first commit including this gitignore and not the files you don't want.

Once the host specific files and such are in the repository they are in the repository and they will make trouble (i.e overwrite new configs on checkout and stuff like this) unless deleted from the repository. So the easiest and safest way to deal with it is not include them at all.

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you. The only think I do not get is how does the colleague gets the config file after checkout if it is missing in Git? Do I have to provide him with it other way? This config file differs instance from instance but is necessary to run the project, only configuration is different each time. What to do in this situation?

Comment: You could include a template config for example project.conf.template, ignore project.conf so it doesn't get commited and then everybody can build his own project.conf based on that template. It basically depends on the type of config. For IDEs I found it easiest just to make a new project in the IDE which generates the necessary configs and then import the sources.